# Javascript possible memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I have the following javascript code, to loop through a number of pages on my server (Used for digital signage).

This code is used in all pages and (at the moment) loops at a page every 3 seconds (see timeout). But, the memory usage of the browser goes up, slowly but steady. After 2 hours it went from 192mb in use to 436mb in use. Since this is on a Raspberry pi with only 512mb memory dedicated to cpu it's not very practical.

Are there any obvious memory leaks in this code? I'm not an expert myself, but since these things will be running 8-12hours a day probably I'm talking about 20reloads/min, so +/- 9600-14400 reloads a day. More if it doesn't get shutdown..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    versionPage = parseInt(document.getElementById("version").innerHTML);
    versionServer = 0
    urls = 0;
    getVersion();
    currentPage = getPage();
    getContent();
    main();

    function getPage() {
        page = window.location.href.split("/");
        return page[page.length-1];
    }

    function getVersion() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/getVersion",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json) {
                console.log("json" + json);
                versionServer = json;
                if (versionServer != versionPage) {
                    console.log("Difference!");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Same!");
                }
            },
       });

    }



    //saves how much urls there are
    function getContent() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/getContent",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json) {
                console.log(json);
                urls = json;
            },       
        });
    }


    //main function loop 
    function main() {
        //check version every 
        window.setInterval(function() {
            getVersion();
            if(versionServer != versionPage) {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/1"
            }
            if(urls != 1) {
                nextPage =(parseInt(currentPage) % urls) + 1;
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:5000/" + nextPage;

            }
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: you pollute the global namespace with your variables, and don't seem to have much experience with async programming, but I don't see anything obvious that would explain a memory-increase in such a dimension. Maybe it's the Browser- keeping history and state (like for forms) and/or Images, ... such things? (just guessing) Have you monitored the traffic, which files are loaded, and how heavy they are.

Comment: They are just plain html files, a few divs, some text, background color. Really as simple as it gets. You are right, i'm far from an experienced JS-writer. Which is why I presume it's something in my programming. All files are local files too. Always the same files, in the test there were 3.

Answer (score 1):

I had to ask you this in comment but it required "50 reputation" to comment.

Have you tried putting your code in an external Javascript file, something like "signagelooper.js" and looing your pages sequentially. This way your looper functions always have one instance running. Correct me if this is what you do not want to do.

Comment: This is what I want to do, but since I have for example 5 pages, I have to reload them, no? I can't just make Javascript replace a complete html page, or am I wrong here? It's already in an external file, but it's called in each page.

Comment: `I can't just make Javascript replace a complete html page, or am I wrong here?` sure you can; as long as you mean the body when you say complete html page. unloading stylesheets and scripts may get nasty, but the rest is no problem.

Comment: I know you can do that, but that would mean completely refactoring the program/system.. And how would I get the html then? I can't access my filesystem? Which would mean I'd have to go through an API I presume? Which will eventually lead to a memory hogging javascript file. Keep in mind that I'm using a raspberry pi here..

Comment: You say this is for Raspberry Pi. I don't know Rpi but you can run this Website on a Windows Machine with Chrome and use the Profiler in Chrome to isolate the Memory Eater. If this is not possible, make sure that the data in browser memory is cleared after every loop which is collected and written to log file.